# Return only the values of an attribute column from a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to return all the values from an attribute (column) in a DynamoDB Table? And does this operation actually have the same computational costs as a `ScanAll` operation?

I have a large enough table, which I don't intend to return all of of its values, but need only some the values from one of the attributes. I am afraid that if I do a `ScanAll` operation and then reduce the data, or `Query` the operational costs will be the same. The workflow as I imagine goes, First, reading all the records receive a blob object and then cutting it to get the attribute in question.

Comment: I'm still not sure if this will will include getting the whole objects (rows) as a result from the query. Additional indexes can be useful for making different queries, but does this still mean that the whole object will be received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs: *GetItem returns all of the item's attributes. You can use a projection expression to return only some of the attributes.*

Having said that, `Projection Expression` *is a string that identifies the attributes that you want. To retrieve a single attribute, specify its name. For multiple attributes, the names must be comma-separated*.

```sh
aws dynamodb get-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key file://key.json \
    --projection-expression "Description, RelatedItems[0], ProductReviews.FiveStar"
```

The arguments for `--key` are stored in the k`ey.json` file.

Full docs on that are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html).